# DynamicScroller in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, overloading, lazy-loading

This is my dynamic scroller component that gets re-rendered after each scroll. Even already rendered and visible cards get re-rendered after scrolling.

What is wrong here?

```xml
<DynamicScroller
  emit-update="false"
  key-field="hotelId"
  :items="data.availableData"
  page-mode
  :min-item-size="300"
  class="scroller"
>
  <DynamicScrollerItem
    :item="item"
    :data-index="index"
    :size-dependencies="item"
    class="py-2"
    :active="active"
  >
    <DTourTicketStyle
      :disable="flag.searchLoading || flag.addBasketLoading"
      :loading="flag.addBasketLoading"
      :search-loading="isSearchFinish"
      :ticket="item"
      :room-passengers="roomPassengers"
      @select="selectHotel"
    />
  </DynamicScrollerItem>
</DynamicScroller>
```

I checked all the props that I found in the package and changed all the amounts.

Comment: **What is wrong here?** - Could you elaborate on what you mean? What is the error? Why is it an error? What would be the expected result? - If we have to grope in the dark, my most ironic response would always be that I think the error is in line 42... **The more details you share about the problem and the more thoroughly you describe it, the sooner you will receive good and accurate answers!**

Comment: If you are using packages and they are part of a public package, please share the package name and version. If these are your own components, it will be necessary to provide information about how the component works because just the attributes alone won't reveal anything about your own code and its structure. Without that information, we won't be able to pinpoint where the error might be located.